# How to let Universal Links only redirect to mobile App from specific paths?

Tags: ios, firebase-hosting, ios-universal-links

I am trying to make use of Universal Links from Apple to link from a url directly into my mobile app, but all the paths are redirecting into the app even if I just want one specific to redirect into the app.

**First thing I did:**

I added the entitlement in Xcode to my app `applinks:xxx.web.app`

**Second:**

I created a apple-app-site-association file:

```html
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "[teamId].[bundleId]",
        "paths": [
          "/redirect",
          "NOT /*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Third:**

I hosted the file via Firebase Hosting (I also tried Vercel first).
The file is accessible and I can see the json in the browser when I enter the URL https://xxx.web.app/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

**Now the Problem:**

I installed the app and https://xxx.web.app/redirect is redirecting into the app as expected. But why is https://xxx.web.app/ and all other paths also redirecting into the app? I would expect that all the other paths are directing to the specific subpages of the website?